# Geoserver basic authentification problem

Tags: geoserver, wfs-t, authentication

I have Geoserver 2.1.3 set up for WFS transaction. I am using basic authentification and I have set up the following:

- A role(ROLE_RMP_WFS)
- A user(user_rmp) which belongs to the role above
- Data security where rmp.*.w is set to the role above and rmp.*.r is set to *
- No service security
- Catalog mode config set to mixed

I can query the layer with WFS just fine.

However, doing a insert post transaction through OpenLayers with the URL _http://user_rmp:rmppassword@kart10utv.ad.skogoglandskap.no/geoserver_ekstern/wfs/
fails with the following message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ows:ExceptionReport version="1.0.0"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows    http://kart10utv:80/geoserver_ekstern/schemas/ows/1.0.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows">
<ows:Exception exceptionCode="InvalidParameterValue">
<ows:ExceptionText>Error performing insert: Cannot access rmp_kartobjekt_flate_v with the current privileges</ows:ExceptionText>
 </ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

However, the object is inserted just fine running the same query in CURL:
curl -vv --header "Content-Type:text/xml" -X POST -d @feature.xml _http://user_rmp:rmppassword@kart10utv.ad.skogoglandskap.no/geoserver_ekstern/wfs

The feature.xml is the same as the POST content:
http://pastebin.com/yPwFb9g7

I do not understand why it works using CURL, but not working using a regular browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Geoserver 2.1.3

By default, no service-level security is set. Two examples are given in the **service.properties** file by default, commented out:

> wfs.GetFeature=ROLE_WFS_READ
>
> wfs.Transaction=ROLE_WFS_WRITE

Make Sure they are included for WFS_T

http://docs.geoserver.org/2.1.3/user/security/sec_service.html

Example Service File with the correct security for anonymous use

http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/_sources/security/service.txt

Note: Restart Geoserver after the file has been edited.

Comment: Ok, I set the role ROLE_RMP_WFS to wfs.Transaction and then it worked in my browser as well. But I still do not understand why it worked using CURL without this setting when it did not work in my browser. Thanks a lot!